# Voicechannel error? "Error: Connection not established within 15 seconds."

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When my discord bot joins a voice channel, then leaves. After a couple of minutes, the bot crashes and says "﻿﻿Error: Connection not established within 15 seconds."

I've tried to update discord.js, doesn't work. Rebooting, nothing. I don't think it's my bot, but maybe discord's fault? I'm just guessing now.

Here's my code for joining a VC:

```
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
        currentStream = connection.playStream(ytdl(
            args[0],
            { filter: 'audioonly' }
        )).catch (err => {
            channelmsg.send(`I was unable to do this command, make sure I have permission to do this. \`ERR: 0xP00002\``)
            return
        });
    });
```

And here's my code for leaving a VC:

```
                        if (voiceChannel) {
                            voiceChannel.leave();
                            var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                                .setColor(0xff0000)
                                .addField('**:play_pause: Music Command.**', `I have now left the voice channel. :wave:`)
                            channelmsg.send({embed});
```

Also voicechannel is just `message.member.voiceChannel;`

Here's the error I get when the bot leaves the VC...

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Error: Connection not established within 15 seconds.
    at VoiceConnection.authenticateFailed (/srv/samba/share/(bot_name)/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/VoiceConnection.js:263:26)
    at connectTimeout.client.setTimeout (/srv/samba/share/(bot_name)/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/VoiceConnection.js:285:18)
    at Timeout.setTimeout (/srv/samba/share/(bot_name)/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:434:7)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:535:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:479:7)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at VoiceConnection.authenticateFailed (/srv/samba/share/(bot_name)/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/VoiceConnection.js:263:12)
    at connectTimeout.client.setTimeout (/srv/samba/share/(bot_name)/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/VoiceConnection.js:285:18)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:479:7)
```

If anyone knows how to fix it, or if there is a new build for discord.js that is known to fix this problem, please let me know in the comments.

Thanks!
-ktg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Quick question: which version of Discord.js do you have installed?

Comment: It's running on 11.5.0

Comment: When you join a voice channel (with your normal user account), does everything function normally? This seems like more of a problem with your connection than Discord.js.

Comment: Yes, very thing does. No disconnections, no glitches or stuff like that.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of delay in an answer! Are you still experiencing this issue? If so, is it consistent?

Comment: Yes I am, like I said in my question, this happens when someone uses the bot to play some music, then when it leaves and after a minute the bot crashes and goes offline.

Comment: If you're still experiencing this issue, I've discovered a possible solution through my own frustration with it. Do you happen to remove listeners from the Client using `EventEmitter.removeAllListeners()`?